# Correct API call to start OpenID connect

Tags: php, openid-connect, onelogin

Having trouble implementing Onelogin/Openid in a simple PHP example. Not sure which API is the correct one to start with. I cannot use any libraries in my code as the destination environment will not allow it, but it will allow PHP/HTML.

We intend to use the Authentication Flow part of the OIDC overview https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect. But this overview does not indicate which API reference to start with. I had assumed https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code which i am able to log into Onelogin without issue but it is not passing back the validated user details so we can confirm them on our system. We have included a valid https callback url in the Configureation of the Openid Connect App and the Login url but these are not triggered by our calls so far.

We are using Grant type 
"The Authentication (or Basic) Flow is designed for apps that have a back end that can communicate with the IdP away from prying eyes."
So we have a backend server to deal with secure authentication.

If https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code is not the correct starting API call then can someone advise which would be the correct call.

Edited to Update: Cracked it. My mistake was not sending the user to the URL. I was treating it like an API call only on the server, when i should have been directing the user to that URL. Re-read the doc and it does say that. Easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate it can look complex, but once you get started it starts to fall into place. Best thing to do is to download the Postman templates or use the new Onelogin OIDC inspector tool as these will pre-build the relevant endpoints for you.

The Inspector is here:
https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/inspector

But for reference, the endpoint to kick off the Authorization flow ( and other flows ) looks like this:

https://{{OIDC_url}}.onelogin.com/oidc/auth?client_id={{OIDC_client_id}}&nonce={{$guid}}&redirect_uri={{OIDC_redirect_uri}}&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=

The vendor documentation for this endpoint is her:
https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code

Let me know how you get on

Comment: Agreed the postman collections have been great from the start, but after testing a live 'working' implementation it feels like starting with an API call is not what i need to be doing. The endpoint you suggest is the one I had been using (in my post ) and I think it is doing what it should be doing. I am logging in and getting the MFA. The issue has been not knowing _**how**_ it should work. I assumed that one uses the API to initiate the login process, then  one would get automatically redirected to our login url set in the portal app config. Its at that point i'm failing.

Comment: Your expectation is correct. In Onelogin, you configure an OIDC application that specifies the redirect URI where your tokens get sent ( you can see the parameter {{OIDC_redirect_URI}} above. Those have to match. You then get your tokens delivered to that endpoint, depending on which flow you have initiated. You then verify and validate the token and make your own decision whether to log the user in to your application or not. https://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-validate-an-openid-connect-id-token

Comment: For *how* it should work, read up on some OIDC documentation. https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect and https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/07/25/oidc-primer-part-1